# How to convert array of tuple to dictionary

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I'm new for psycopg2 and postgress, i can able to retrieve data from 
postgress. but I'm facing following issue

```
      kart_user = "kart_user"
      token = 'acf98c76a70a4a67b6d503377279c7da'
      cond = "token"+ " = " +"'{}'".format(token)
      cur = conn.cursor()
      cur.execute("SELECT * FROM "+ kart_user +" where "+cond +" ;")
      res = cur.fetchall()
      data = cur.fetchall()
      print data
```

Output

```
[('acf98c76a70a4a67b6d503377279c7da', 'sssssssss', 'hello', 'sssssss')]
```

Output is array of tuple format ,i want to retrieve in the form of dictionary

```
eg:  data['token']
```

How can i solve this issue? thank you

Comment: What are the keys and what are the values in the dictionary you want to build?

Comment: key is table column and value is column values

Comment: Have you seen the [psycopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor) ?

Comment: Unrelated -The code you posted suffers from potential SQL injection. Please [pass parameters to ``.execute`` separately](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the table name and condition?

Answer (score 0):

```
DataDictionary ={} //out of the data collection loop

while collectingData==True:
    DataDictionary['%s'%token] = data[0][1:]
```

this will create a dictionary and add a entry with the token (in string form) as a key. If another variable is suitable as a unique key you could use that.

retrieve a specific key using one of the methods below

```
DataDictionary['acf98c76a70a4a67b6d503377279c7da'] = ('sssssssss', 'hello', 'sssssss')

or DataDictionary[token] = ('sssssssss', 'hello', 'sssssss')
```

If you want the data in the form of a dictionary you must first create the dictionary with the line:

```
DictionaryName={ }
```

This initialisation of the dictionary should be done outside of the data collection loop or you will lose the old data.

You could simplify the data addition line to:

```
DataDictionary['%s'%token] = data
```

But this keeps the data nested in unnecessary lists. If it needs to be simpler
then perhaps i am not understanding what you really need from this.